# a way to count the number of nodes on-screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, core-graphics

Someone please push me in the right direction.

Here's the thing: what I'm trying to do is to limit the amount of projectiles (shot by player) that can be on screen. That limit is recorded in a constant. So while the number of projectile nodes on the screen is equal to that constant, the player will not be able to shoot any more.

Once a projectile goes off screen, that projectile is getting removed, decreasing the amount of on-screen nodes, and the player should be able to shoot again, of course without exceeding the limit. (The shots are being done using a push of a button, not tapping the screen in the direction you want to shoot, if that is important. You can only shoot one at a time.)

What kind of algorithm can I use to solve this? How to keep up the number of projectiles currently on-screen? How to let the system know WHEN to decrease that amount (I've been using collision detection, having a "screen bounds node") and WHAT node to remove (I've been recording node ID in the name, but looks like doing that the wrong way)? Please suggest a solid solution to this. Hope what I have requested is possible.

Comment: CGRectIntersectsRect with sprite.frame and scene.frame let's you determine if a sprite is onscreen. The rest is simply reference-counting, ie increase a counter when you add a bullet, decrease it when you remove a bullet, don't allow new bullets when counter >= limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have made two claims here:

1. A projectile is created when shot by a player.
2. A projectile is deleted when it goes off screen.

If you already have code removing the projectile when it goes off screen, you could just leverage a simple `static` count:

```
@implementation Projectile
static NSUInteger projectileCount = 0;
+ (instancetype)fireProjectile {
  if (projectileCount < MAX_PROJECTILES) {
    projectileCount++;
    return [[Projectile alloc] init];
  }
  return nil;
}
- (void)dealloc {
  projectileCount--;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you want, but based on what I have read you could have an array of projectiles that contains the amount of projectiles you want to allow.

```
// create an array
NSMutableArray *projectiles = [NSMutableArray array];

// populate the array with your projectiles

for (int index = 0;index < kMaxProjectiles;index++)
{
    Projectile *projectile = [[Projectile alloc]init];
    [projectiles addObject:projectile]
}
```

Now whenever you want to shoot a projectile, remove it from that array and shoot it.

```
Projectile *projectile = [projectiles objectAtIndex:0];
[projectiles removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

When it goes off the screen, remove it from the parent and push it right back into the array.

```
[projectile removeFromParent];
[projectiles addObject:projectile];
```

It's basically a pooling system where you would create your projectiles once and recycle them. When choosing to shoot, you can just check the count of the array to determine if you have a projectile available :

```
if (projectiles.count > 0)
{
   // yep, there are projectiles in the pool, fire away
}
```

Added advantage of pooling is that you are not constantly creating and killing your projectiles, which will result in pauses when Garbage Collection occurs or if you ever tried to create alot of projectiles at once.